# Relation between system RAM capacity and VRAM capacity?

Tags: memory, gpu, vram

There are some months ago, I saw on a forum (sorry, I do not have the URL!) that we need to respect a ratio of 4:1 between the capacity of the system RAM and VRAM. For example, having 16 GB of system RAM with a graphics card that has 4 GB of VRAM.

To what extent is this true? Are there any correlation between the capacities of both RAMs? Their frequency is it also important?

Thank you for your answers !

**EDIT**: To be exhaustive, I talk about a gamer PC with relatively good graphics card.

Comment: I'd say someone's trying to set up a 'rule of thumb', for which I suppose it's a fair 'rule' if you're looking at gamer machines, where a 4GB card on a 2GB machine would be as wasted as a 1GB card on a 16GB machine. It doesn't extend very far though - there's no way I really think I'm gonna need a 16GB card just because I have 64GB system RAM - & it doesn't take anything else into consideration; relative speeds, whether the game buffers its RAM back to system RAM.

Answer (score 1):

> To what extent is this true? 
>   Are there any correlation between the capacities of both RAMs?

For the most part there are no correlations. You can be perfectly happy with no video memory at all.

The only correlation I can think of is that if you play games. If you have a a fast computer than many people also expect a fast graphics card. But that only makes sense in the same way that a modern car 'requires' cruise control.
(In other words: it does not).

Comment: To be exhaustive, I talk about a PC of with relatively good graphics card (2 GB or more VRAM).

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation that has to be maintained between the amount of RAM and VRAM. It is just like another similar statement I heard stating the the amount of RAM should be in a multiple of 4(in GB).
You can have as much amount of RAM as you want and still not have any VRAM on your system (although the CPU-integrated VRAM is still present).

I have used systems with 4:1 ,2:1,1:1 and even 1:2 ratios of RAM and VRAM, and it makes no difference, except the obvious one that the RAM must be enough so as to not bottleneck the performance of the game/application you are running.

You must have read about the recommended 4:1 ratio because generally the games which put a huge load on the GPU (e.g 2 GB) are also memory-hogs, and thus require RAM equal to or greater than 8 GBs.